# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: while running .bat file

Tags: java

I have bat file like below with name `myBat.bat`

1)

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk\Desktop\3611 java\
javac packbat/inter.java
java packbat.samplepack
pause
```

2) interface "inter" inside package packbat

```
package packbat;
public interface inter
{
    int i=10;   
}
```

3) my main()class inside package packbat

```
package packbat;
public class samplepack implements inter
{
   public static void main(String s[])
   {
     System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

After clicking that .bat file it displays this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: packbat/inter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packbat.inter
```

How to run that .bat file without error.

Comment: Is the packbat directory in the same directory from which you're running the batch file? Or is it in a different place?

Comment: all the files are in same directory.
C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk\Desktop\3611 java\packbat\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake into your mybat.bat.

You don't compile the interface, you must compile the samplepack.java and not the inter.java.
Moreover take care about your CLASSPATH because there is space into the PATH. Add quote around like that:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk\Desktop\3611 java\";
```

And to finish if you use the "javac packbat/samplepack.java" you must put your mybat.bat into the parent directory of your java files.

Comment: @echo off

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk 
\Desktop\3611 java\"; 

javac packbat.samplepack.java

java packbat.samplepack
pause

as per your suggestion , i do the changes, yet im getting the same error

Comment: I have tried it at home and it works fine.
My bat file looks like this and it's located in the parent folder of the package:

@echo off
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk\Desktop\3611 java\"
javac packbat\samplepack.java
java packbat.samplepack
pause

Comment: I'd just add that my package folder is located in the "C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk \Desktop\3611 java\".
So you must put your package folder (packbat) and the myBat.bat in this path. (Btw your classes must be in the packbat folder)

Answer (score 0):

Try 
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Documents and Settings\nchakk\Desktop\3611 java\"

(put quotes around the path since it contains spaces).

Comment: Im getting this error   -
javac: file not found: packbat.samplepack.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: packbat/samplepack
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packbat.samplepack
    
Could not find the main class: packbat.samplepack.  Program will exit.
Press any key to continue . . .